# Tables not showing in HTML database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am creating a database and when creating the HTML script the table is coming back with no boarders = Firstname Lastname ";

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo ""; 
    echo "" . $row['Firstname'] . ""; 
    echo "" . $row['Lastname'] . ""; 
    echo ""; 
} 
echo ""; 
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Here is the code I created, could someone look at it and tell me what I have done wrong?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Franchise_Call_Log");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM caller_info");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
th>Franchise</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Franchise'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You miss some code post them.

Comment: what is your file name and where are you running this script(wamp/lamp/xammp)?

Comment: Post what you are getting as output.

Comment: I am using xammp, the output is at the top but here it is again. Firstname Lastname th>Franchise "; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo ""; echo "" . $row['Firstname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['Lastname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['Franchise'] . ""; echo ""; } echo ""; mysqli_close($con); ?>

Comment: so your problem is that table border is not displaying.right?

Comment: Are you sure your file extension is `.php`?

Comment: No my file extension is html and correct my borders are not displaying, that is my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your file extension to `.php` it is not rendering your script. Html file not render your php, and also correct your markup as suggested by @suhail.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the  tag

```
<th>Franchise</th>
```